# Using Shamsi/Persian Date in D3 and DC.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

How can i use Persian or Jalali or Shamsi Date in `D3` or `DC.js` . for example if i have bar chart that  X-axis contains date i want to sort the date based on Persian date that.

Comment: I don't know much about non-Gregorian dates, but my understanding is that you would still use standard JavaScript dates and then set [axis.tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) to print the dates using an alternate calendar.

Comment: @Gordon your idea may helpful. but i need to re arrange and sort and draw charts base on non-Gregorian date, can you send me an example of your idea . thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the topic in particular but do know the concepts. So I hope this helps, but I haven't tried it.

The [underlying JavaScript time type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 UTC (the ["epoch"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)). So the sorting and difference calculations are not specific to any calendar.

It is just the Date API and D3 that use the Gregorian calendar.

There are a number of libraries to convert Jalali/Shamsi to/from epoch time and JS Dates, just do a google search e.g. for "javascript jalali date".

Build your data set by converting Jalali dates to javascript dates, and specify the format for your axis using [axis.tickFormat](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat), using the converter in the other direction.